# Animations Timings for different Images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

guys i have set five different imageview in XML i want same animation effect with one second delay.Animation must occur in sequence order one by one.For a starting page in android app i have done this.so what should i do here's my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

a=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
c=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
d=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
e=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

aAnimation(savedInstanceState);
bAnimation(savedInstanceState);
cAnimation(savedInstanceState);
dAnimation(savedInstanceState);
eAnimation(savedInstanceState);
}

private void aAnimation(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Animation aa=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slideup);
    a.startAnimation(aa);

}
private void bAnimation(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Animation aa=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slideup);
    b.startAnimation(aa);

}
private void cAnimation(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Animation aa=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slideup);
    c.startAnimation(aa);

}
private void dAnimation(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Animation aa=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slideup);
    d.startAnimation(aa);

}
private void eAnimation(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Animation aa=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slideup);
    e.startAnimation(aa);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use a CountDownTimer and call your animations in sequence. Interval = 1000ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Handler`s with delay

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
    {
      // run animation
    }
 }, 1000); //1 sec
```

Comment: can you follow chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era

Comment: sry i dont have 20 reputation i will post as another question

Comment: i have mailed  u my question

Answer (score 2):

You can use **startOffset**

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html
>
> Delay in milliseconds before the animation runs, once start time is
> reached.

For example:

In XML :

```
<set android:startOffset="1000"> 
    <scale 
       android:fromXScale="0.5" 
       android:toXScale="1.0" 
       android:fromYScale="0.5" 
       android:toYScale="1.0" 
       android:pivotX="50%" 
       android:pivotY="50%" 
       android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

OR

In JAVA :

```
Animation aa = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slideup);
aa.setStartOffset(1000);
a.startAnimation(aa);
```